# Authentication from mobile app NativeScript Vue

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, nativescript

I am developing a mobile application with NativeScript & Vue (Ts) and I am questioning myself!

I have to develop the login page & the login process for the mobile app and I really don't know which choice is the better.
I need to communicate between My App and My Website which have the exact same purpose. Plus I expect my user to keep logged after first login on the app.

- I started to think to give access to the data on my website by developing a REST API (API Platform + Symfony + JWT Token).
- Now I think of using OAuth2 for the exchange (get token, get refreshtoken etc...).
- Now I wonder should I just send an HTTPS POST Request and generate tokens by myself?

Has anyone done this before?
Have you any suggestions?
Also which process is the better in my case: Implicit Grant or Password Grant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend Firebase Authentication.  There is core support for Firebase Authentication in Nativescript, found here: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/firebase-auth.html#authentication

It's very simple to set up:

```
import { firebase } from '@nativescript/firebase-core'
import '@nativescript/firebase-auth' // only needs to be imported 1x

const auth = firebase().auth()
```

An example of logging in:

```
firebase.firebase
.login({ type: firebase.firebase.LoginType.GOOGLE })
.then(() => {
    this.loadUser();
});
```

From there, I would use the Firebase permissions to handle user permissions.  That's a bit outside the scope of the question, but I personally use custom claims to handle different permission levels (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).